# Macbook Air doesn't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, power-management

I have a 2017 Macbook Air 2017. A week ago I turned it on and  wrote my password, then it shut down. I tried to turn on but nothing happened. I read some posts on the Internet and tried the following:

1. Unplug the MagSafe 2.
2. Open my MacBook Air.
3. Disconnect the battery.
4. Plug in the MagSafe 2.
5. Reset the SMC (pressing Left Shift, Option, Control and Power for ten seconds and releasing at the same time).
6. Connect the battery.
7. Press power and Voila, It Turn On!

I was using my Macbook very happy but now when I shut down my MacBook to go to sleep, the next day when I try to turn it on, nothing happened. It stay shut down like at the beginning and I have to repeat the steps to turn it on.

Whats is the problem with my MacBook?  What do you recommend me to do? Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: When and where did you bought it from? Is it covered under original warranty or Apple Care?

Comment: You're resetting the SMC by virtue of disconnecting the battery.  Try without the manual SMC reset, because, when you do that, you're actually turning the unit on.

Comment: Hi Nimesh Neema, My macbook isn't covered under warranty,because I brought it in Sams Club's by Walmart a year ago and the warranty expired.

Comment: Hi Allan, I tried disconnecting the battery and turn the macbook on but notthing happened, It turn on when I reset the SMC without the battery.